# When inputting data in the forms, the input boxes is not updating the 'shopping cart'. {JavaScript}

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out where there are any error(s). When the information is entered in the forms to the left and tab out of the input boxes after entering the information, it should update the field to the right (shopping cart).

[image: Shopping Cart Form]

However that is not happening and I'm not sure where I went wrong in the code. I did go through and fix quite a few errors on my end and any that showed up in my console. At this point I'm stuck.

JavaScript code:

```
"use strict";

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Calculate the shopping cart when the page loads
    calcCart();

    // Verify that the user has selected a session to attend
    document.getElementById("regSubmit").click = sessionTest;

    // Recalculate the shopping chart when any field loses the focus
    document.getElementById("fnBox").blur = calcCart;
    document.getElementById("lnBox").blur = calcCart;
    document.getElementById("groupBox").blur = calcCart;
    document.getElementById("mailBox").blur = calcCart;
    document.getElementById("phoneBox").blur = calcCart;
    document.getElementById("sessionBox").blur = calcCart;
    document.getElementById("banquetBox").blur = calcCart;
    document.getElementById("mediaCB").blur = calcCart;
});


// Function to verify that a session was selected by the user
function sessionTest() {
    var confSession = document.getElementById("sessionBox")[i];
    if (confSession.selectedIndex < 0) {
        confSession.setValidity("Select a Session Package");
    } else {
        confSession.setValidity("");
    }
}

// Function to calculate the shopping cart total
function calcCart() {

    // Calculate the banquet cost for all guests
    let guestCost = document.forms.register.elements.banquetGuests.value*55;
    document.getElementById("regBanquet").textContent = document.forms.register.elements.banquetGuests.value;

    // Determine the cost of the selected session
    let sessionCost = 0;        // Initial cost of the session
    let sessionChoice = "";     // Initial chosen session

    // Index of the chosen session
    let selectedSession = document.forms.register.elements.sessionBox.selectedIndex;

    // Retrieve the name and cost of the selected session
    if (selectedSession.selected >= 0) {
        sessionChoice = document.forms.register.elements.sessionBox[selectedSession].textContent;
        sessionCost = document.forms.register.elements.sessionBox[selectedSession].value;
    }

    // Determine the cost of the media pack
    let mediaCost = 0;       // Initial media cost
    let mediaChoice = "";    // Initial media choice

    // If the user selects the media pack, update the choice and cost
    if (document.forms.register.elements.mediaCB.checked === true) {
        mediaChoice = "yes"
        mediaCost = 115;
    }

    // Calculate total cost of the conference
    // Multiply field values by 1 to convert them from text strings to numeric values
    let totalCost = guestCost*1 + sessionCost*1 + mediaCost*1;

    // Display the field values and calculated values in the Shopping Cart table
    document.getElementById("regName").textContent = document.forms.register.elements.firstName.value + " " + document.forms.register.elements.lastName.value;
    document.getElementById("regGroup").textContent = document.forms.register.elements.group.value;
    document.getElementById("regEmail").textContent = document.forms.register.elements.email.value;
    document.getElementById("regPhone").textContent = document.forms.register.elements.phoneNumber.value;
    document.getElementById("regSession").textContent = sessionChoice.sel;
    document.getElementById("regBanquet").textContent = document.forms.register.elements.banquetGuests.value;
    document.getElementById("regPack").textContent = mediaChoice;
    document.getElementById("regTotal").textContent = totalCost.toLocaleString("en-US", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"});
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Hands-on Project 6-5</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
   <script src="project06-05.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <h1>
         Hands-on Project 6-5
      </h1>
   </header>

   <article>
   <section>
      <h1>Registration Page</h1>
      <form id="register" name="register" method="get" action="formsubmit.html">
         <fieldset id="contactInfo">    
            <label for="fnBox">First Name*</label>
            <input name="firstName" id="fnBox" type="text" required />

            <label for="lnBox">Last Name*</label>
            <input name="lastName" id="lnBox" type="text" required />

            <label for="groupBox">Company or University</label>
            <input name="group" id="groupBox" type="text" />

            <label for="mailBox">E-mail*</label>
            <input name="email" id="mailBox" type="email" required />

            <label for="phoneBox">Phone Number*</label>
            <input name="phoneNumber" id="phoneBox" type="tel" pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$"
                   required placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" />
         </fieldset>
         
         <fieldset id="confChoices">
            <label for="sessionBox">Session Packs</label>
            <select id="sessionBox" name="sessionOption" size="5" required>
               <option value="95">Exhibits Only ($95)</option>
               <option value="215">3 Session Pack ($215)</option>
               <option value="420">6 Session Pack ($420)</option>
               <option value="595">Session Pass ($595)</option>
               <option value="845">VIP Pass ($845)</option>
            </select>
            <label for="banquet">MAS22 Banquet ($55 ea.)</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="10" id="banquetBox" name="banquetGuests" /><span> attendees</span>          
            
            <label for="mediaPack">MAS22 Media Pack ($115)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mediaPack" id="mediaCB" value="115" />  
               
         </fieldset> 
         
         <input id="regSubmit" type="submit" value="continue" />
      </form>
   </section>
   
   <aside id="reg1Aside">
      <table>
         <caption>Shopping Cart</caption>
         <tr><th>Name</th><td><span id="regName"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>Company</th><td><span id="regGroup"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>E-mail</th><td><span id="regEmail"></span></td></tr>         
         <tr><th>Phone</th><td><span id="regPhone"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>Session</th><td><span id="regSession"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>Banquet Guests ($55 ea.)</th><td><span id="regBanquet"></span></td></tr> 
         <tr><th>Media Pack ($115)</th><td><span id="regPack"></span></td></tr>
         <tr><th>TOTAL</th><td><span id="regTotal"></span></td></tr> 
      </table>                                               
   </aside>
   </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried sticking some debugging statements in your JS functions? Do you know if your event listeners are being fired?

Comment: Also, regarding `document.getElementById("fnBox").blur = calcCart;`, et al., I think you want to add an event listener, but `.blur` doesn't do that. I recommend reading the [documentation for addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.onchange` onevent property or "change" event with `.addEventListener()`. Also, the `<form>` is wrapped around everything so you can use [`<output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) instead of `<span>`. Also, everything now references the `<form>` via the [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) interface, in which I saw that you were using but not to it's fullest extent:

```
const REG = document.forms.register;
const IO = REG.elements;
```

Removed `.setValidity()` since it wasn't really part of the question, and because it's [not supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementInternals/setValidity#browser_compatibility). BTW, 99% of the time you should place all `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag. One small thing, you should make the phone number validation a little more relaxed, it's easier for the user to input: "123-456-7890" than it is to enter "(123) 456-789". Also, why do you want `calcCart()` to run at load? Do you have data the user entered previously?

The choice of tags are very semantic and the style (from what I see in the image) is slick.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Hands-on Project 6-5</title>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Hands-on Project 6-5</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <form id="register" name="register" method="get" action="formsubmit.html">
      <section>
        <h2>Registration Page</h2>
        <fieldset name="contactInfo" class='contactInfo'>
          <legend>Contact Information</legend>
          <label for="fnBox">First Name*</label>
          <input id="fnBox" name="firstName" type="text" required />
          <label for="lnBox">Last Name*</label>
          <input id="lnBox" name="lastName" type="text" required />
          <label for="groupBox">Company or University</label>
          <input id="groupBox" name="group" type="text" />
          <label for="mailBox">E-mail*</label>
          <input id="mailBox" name="email" type="email" required />
          <label for="phoneBox">Phone Number*</label>
          <input id="phoneBox" name="phoneNumber" type="tel" pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" required placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset name="confChoices" class='confChoices'>
          <legend>Conference Choices</legend>
          <label for="sessionBox">Session Packs</label>
          <select id="sessionBox" name="sessionOption" required>
            <option value="95">Exhibits Only ($95)</option>
            <option value="215">3 Session Pack ($215)</option>
            <option value="420">6 Session Pack ($420)</option>
            <option value="595">Session Pass ($595)</option>
            <option value="845">VIP Pass ($845)</option>
          </select>
          <label for="banquetBox">MAS22 Banquet ($55 ea.)</label>
          <input id="banquetBox" name="banquetGuests" type="number" min="0" max="10" /><label for='banquetBox'> attendees</label>
          <label for="mediaCB">MAS22 Media Pack ($115)</label>
          <input id="mediaCB" name="mediaPack" type="checkbox" value="115" />
        </fieldset>
        <button>Continue</button>
      </section>
      <aside class="regSummary">
        <table>
          <caption>Registration Summary</caption>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><output id="regName"></output></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <td><output id="regGroup"></output></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <td><output id="regEmail"></output></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <td><output id="regPhone"></output></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Session</th>
            <td><output id="regSession"></output></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Banquet Guests ($55 ea.)</th>
            <td><output id="regBanquet"></output></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Media Pack ($115)</th>
            <td><output id="regPack"></output></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
            <td><output id="regTotal"></output></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </aside>
    </form>
  </main>
  <script>
  const REG = document.forms.register;
  const IO = REG.elements;
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    /*
    Recalculate the summary when any field data is entered and loses the focus
    */
    IO.fnBox.onchange = calcCart;
    IO.lnBox.onchange = calcCart;
    IO.groupBox.onchange = calcCart;
    IO.mailBox.onchange = calcCart;
    IO.phoneBox.onchange = calcCart;
    IO.sessionBox.onchange = calcCart;
    IO.banquetBox.onchange = calcCart;
    IO.mediaCB.onchange = calcCart;
  });
  // Function to calculate the summary total
  function calcCart() {
    // Calculate the banquet cost for all guests
    let guestCost = +IO.banquetGuests.value * 55;
    // Index of the chosen session
    let selectedSession = IO.sessionBox.selectedIndex;
    let sessionChoice = IO.sessionBox[selectedSession].text;
    let sessionCost = +IO.sessionBox.value;
    // If Media is checked
    let mediaCost = IO.mediaCB.checked ? +IO.mediaCB.value : 0;
    let mediaChoice = IO.mediaCB.checked ? "Yes" : "No";
    // Calculate total cost of the conference
    let totalCost = guestCost + sessionCost + mediaCost;
    // Display the field values and calculated values in the Summary table
    IO.regName.value = IO.firstName.value + " " + IO.lastName.value;
    IO.regGroup.value = IO.group.value;
    IO.regEmail.value = IO.mailBox.value;
    IO.regPhone.value = IO.phoneBox.value;
    IO.regSession.value = sessionChoice;
    IO.regBanquet.value = IO.banquetBox.value;
    IO.regPack.value = mediaChoice;
    IO.regTotal.value = totalCost.toLocaleString("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD"
    });
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have added eventlistener 'load', this will be invoked after document loaded, can try 'change' or 'click' eventlisteners if you want data to be updated after input box change